# Regular Expression High CPU

Tags: java, regex

We are encountering issues in our production environment with 100% CPU utilization and thread dump shows our "Black List" implementation stuck on following.

```
[11/14/13 10:12:42:745 CST] 0000000d ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "Thread-002" (0000003b) has been active for 604063 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
    at java.lang.Character.isLetterOrDigit(Character.java:3516)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Bound.check(Pattern.java:4820)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Bound.match(Pattern.java:4832)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3366)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.match(Matcher.java:1127)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.matches(Matcher.java:502)
```

The problem is this does not happen always which mean it is data dependent and we have following list of Regular Expressions in our Black List implementation.

I would appreciate if someone can tell which regular expression out of the following can potentially cause the 100% CPU (I would guess due to back tracking).

```
# zero/null bytes 
.*\x00.*

# javascript
.*\bjavascript\b.* &&! ^[\w.,;/*+= -]*\b(:?application/x-javascript|text/javascript)\b[\w.,;/*+= -]*$
# vbscript
.*\bvbscript\b.*

# <script or </script>
.*<\s*/?\s*script\b.*|.*\bscript\s*>.*
# <img or </img>
.*<\s*/?\s*img\b.*|.*\bimg\s*>.*
# <div or </div>
.*<\s*/?\s*div\b.*|.*\bdiv\s*>.*
# <html or </html>
.*<\s*/?\s*html\b.*|.*\bhtml\s*>.*
# <body or </body>
.*<\s*/?\s*body\b.*|.*\bbody\s*>.*
# <link or </link>
.*<\s*/?\s*link\b.*|.*\blink\s*>.* &&! ^<\?xml .*$
# <meta or </meta>
.*<\s*/?\s*meta\b.*|.*\bmeta\s*>.*
# <base or </base>
.*<\s*/?\s*base\b.*|.*\bbase\s*>.*
# <span or </span>
.*<\s*/?\s*span\b.*|.*\bspan\s*>.*
# <input or </input>
.*<\s*/?\s*input\b.*|.*\binput\s*>.*
# <style or </style>
.*<\s*/?\s*style\b.*|.*\bstyle\s*>.*
# <table or </table>
.*<\s*/?\s*table\b.*|.*\btable\s*>.*
# <embed or </embed>
.*<\s*/?\s*embed\b.*|.*\bembed\s*>.*
# <frame or </frame>
.*<\s*/?\s*frame\b.*|.*\bframe\s*>.*
# <iframe or </iframe>
.*<\s*/?\s*iframe\b.*|.*\biframe\s*>.*
# <object or </object>
.*<\s*/?\s*object\b.*|.*\bobject\s*>.*

# < onload= >
.*<.+\bonload\s*=.+>.*
# < onerror= >
.*<.+\bonerror\s*=.+>.*
# < onmouseover= >
.*<.+\bonmouseover\s*=.+>.*
# < src= >
.*<.+\bsrc\s*=.+>.*
# < href= >
.*<.+\bhref\s*=.+>.*
# < style= >
.*<.+\bstyle\s*=.+>.*
# < content= >
.*<.+\bcontent\s*=.+>.*

# document.
.*\bdocument\s*\..+
# element.
.*\belement\s*\..+

# url(
.*\burl\s*\(.+
# eval(
.*\beval\s*\(.+
# alert(
.*\balert\s*\(.+

# /* */
.*/\*.*\*/.*


# HTTP response splitting
.*\bHTTP/\d+\.\d+.+


# Path traversal
#.*\.\.[/\\].*
.*\.\.[/\\]\.\.[/\\].*


# SQL injection (probably not very useful)

# from HttpServletBase.java
.*select\s+\S*\s*from\s+\S+(?:\s+where\s+.+)?.*
.*insert\s+\S*\s*into\s+\S+(?:\s+values\s+.+)?.*
.*update\s+\S*\s*set\s+\S+(?:\s+where\s+.+)?.*
.*delete\s+\S*\s*from\s+\S+(?:\s+where\s+.+)?.*
```

Comment: How are you using these regular expressions? You can save a lot of CPU by reusing Pattern objects.

Comment: Yes we precompile them. The issue seems to be based on some data that comes in 100% CPU gets used up, it does not happen all the time so looking for some help to pinpoint whcih Regex may be causing issues e.g. backtracking etc.

Comment: My go-to argument about performance is that you are the only one who can know what is slow :) Find a few samples of data that exhibit the problem, put them in a kind of unit test, then activate/disactivate some regex to see which ones are problematic.

Comment: I bumped into the same problem once, and I was dealing with expressions so simple that I could make an hypothesis on what made it slow. Unfortunately, I can't remember anymore. I suggest you to try and reproduce the issue with simpler, but still tricky, expressions.

Comment: Two words: [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Also, you fail to mention which java regex function and regex modifiers you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I say in the comments, proper testing of the data is the only way to really know which regex is problematic. But I think there is something I can pinpoint and you can look into. Basically, be careful about the dot operator.

Look at:

```
.*<.+\bonload\s*=.+>.*
```

I guess you want to find any HTML tag that contains "onload". The thing is, if you have data with a lot of tags, and none contain "onload", it will do like this:

1. Find the first `<`
2. Go through the rest of the string to find "\bonload"
3. Since none can be found, backtrack and try with the following `<` in the string.

This will therefore be repeated for every tag in the string, so step 2 can be expensive if your string is long. You can optimize by preventing it to go past the end of the tag by replacing `.+` with `[^>]+` (that is, anything but a `>`).

So the following regex should perform better:

```
.*<[^>]+\bonload\s*=.+>.*
```

Also, following the general principle that "the fastest code is the code that doesn't run", you can look if the string contains the string "onload" with a simple string search before using a regular expression.

Comment: Thank you very it turned out that one of the parameters contained XML which had a lot of "<" ">" and the XML was large enough and back tracking caused CPU to run high. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but regular expression won't save you from XSS attacks, as they can be very tricky: [XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet). You might want to have a look at [OWASP's HTML sanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/).

For a similar problem in my project I came with a solution which combined JSoup to parse HTML and regular expressions to match strings in attributes and text (I was not aware of this OWASP tool at that moment).